# How to avoid Superagent response resolving the async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, superagent

I have an async function with a request (superagent) in it. Every time the response from the request comes back, the whole function is resolved immidiately. How can I avoid this behaviour? :/

```
getToken: async ()  => {

        
            await request
                .post('https://tokenAdress')
                .field('client_id', process.env.CLIENT_ID)
                .field('client_secret', process.env.CLIENT_SECRET)
                .field('grant_type', 'client_credentials')
                .then( (response) => {

                         // do some stuff with response
                         return resultOfStuffDone;
                }).catch( err => {
                    
                    throw new Error(errorMessages.couldNotGetToken);
                })
 }
```

and ...

```
async () => {

        let bla = await ApiEndpoints.getToken();

        console.log(bla); // undefined 

}
```

Would be appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getToken: async ()  => {

    
        let response = await request
            .post('https://tokenAdress')
            .field('client_id', process.env.CLIENT_ID)
            .field('client_secret', process.env.CLIENT_SECRET)
            .field('grant_type', 'client_credentials')
            .catch( err => {
                
                throw new Error(errorMessages.couldNotGetToken);
            })
     if(response !== undefined){
     //do something
      return resultOfStuffDone
     }
  }
```

When you use await the value can be assigned to a variable instead of using then.

Comment: Thank you very much!